# How can I disable the sdk update search when launch the android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I use a `sdk` folder that it supports until the `API17`, because I do not need the higher `API`. I have android studio 1.3 and but when I launch the android studio wizard and I want to create a new project 
I see the following annoying Message. How can I disable the sdk update search when launch the android studio?

[image]